# Is there a way to control AngularJs exception catching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

AngularJS seems to wrap user-provided callbacks into `try-catch`. This may be useful in production, however I can miss critical exceptions during development.

How can I turn this feature off? I want Angular not to catch or to rethrow all exceptions in user code.

Example:

```
 $http.get(someUrl)
    .success(function(data){
            //bla-bla-bla
    })
    .finally(function(){
        $scope.functionA(); //division by zero exception inside
        $scope.functionB();
    });
```

I get unhandled exception inside `functionA`, and `functionB` is never executed. Normally exception bubbles to the top and I see a red message in console. But this time I did not, so it took me 5 minutes to debug what has happened.

**PS**: Chrome devtools has an option to pause on handled exceptions. I get a lot of them unfortunately, but most seem to be thrown and handled internally in AngularJS. I have either an app full of invisible bugs or this is normal for Angular. Whatever, is there any way to tell angular not to swallow exceptions like in example?

Comment: Our development has been crippled because of this, thanks for pointing out the devtools option!

Comment: Angular and their http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling